# Using OAuth with Google Calendar API PHP library

Tags: php, oauth

The Google Calendar API version 1 PHP library only contains example code for AuthSub. If I wanted to use OAuth, is that possible?

Comment: Yep: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550143/google-calendar-api-and-oauth-problem

Comment: True, but you asked if its possible. It IS possible. If it can be done in Java, it can be done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html
and use some php lib that let you handle OAuth1.0 I know some developers worked with: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use OAuth with Google Calendar API PHP library keep in mind these changes were required to achieve this:

Within the OAuth options array that you pass to the Zend_Oauth_Consumer:

'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER
had to be changed to
'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_QUERYSTRING

and within the Zend_Gdata_Calendar class

```
const CALENDAR_EVENT_FEED_URI = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full';
```

had to be changed to
    const CALENDAR_EVENT_FEED_URI = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full';

as we were requesting the Data from a HTTPS page, and the protocols had to line up.

Ben.